# computing $P\left(\max(U_{(1)}, U_{(2)}-U_{(1)}, \cdots,U_{(n)}-U_{(n-1)} ) <a\right)$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, extreme-value, order-statistics

Let $U_{1}, \, ... \, ,U_{n}$ be a random sample of uniform random variables $U_i \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$. Let $U_{(1)}, \, ... \, , U_{(n)}$ be the order statistics of the sample. My problem is to find
$$
P\left(\max(U_{(1)}, U_{(2)}-U_{(1)}, \cdots,U_{(n)}-U_{(n-1)} ) <a\right).
$$
where $a$ is a positive fixed value.
My guess is that I can use the following relationship
$$
U_{(s)}-U_{(r)} \sim \textrm{Beta}(s-r, \, n - s + r +1) \qquad 1 \leq r < s \leq n.
$$
Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
P\left(\max(U_{(1)}, U_{(2)}-U_{(1)}, \cdots,U_{(n)}-U_{(n-1)} ) <a\right)&=&P\left(\max(U_{(1)}, U_{(1)}, \cdots,U_{(1)} ) <a\right)\\
&=&P\left(U_{(1)} <a\right)\\
&=&\int_0^a n(1-x)^{n-1} dx\\
&=& 1-(1-a)^n
\end{eqnarray}
I doubt it to be correct! Please help me.

Comment: Yes, you can't assume independence between different $U_{(i)}-U_{(i-1)}$.  There may be some connection to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/412037/conditional-distribution-of-arrival-times-in-poisson-process.  If this is homework then add `self-study` (not that I see any simple solution).

Comment: Welcome to CV Math Universe! Cool question, and it made me think about the uniform distribution in a new way. :) Quick question: is $0 \le a \le 1$? Or is $0 \le a$?

Comment: Thank you, Suppose that $0 \leq a \leq 1$. By the way, It is not a homework question.

Comment: @Alexis For $a \geq 1$, I think the probability is equal to 1.

Comment: The spacing$$(U_{(1)},U_{(2)}-U_{(1)},\ldots,1-U_{(n)})$$is a Dirichlet $\mathcal D_{n+1}(1,\ldots,1)$ random vector.

Comment: @MathUniverse Part of he question mentioned $1 - (1 - a)^n$, which was why I asked if $a$ was over the range $0$ to $1$.

Comment: @Xi'an Indeed Devroye's lemma gives the answer and more...

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you for your help, How can I from $\mathbb P\left(\max(U_{(1)}, U_{(2)}-U_{(1)}, \cdots,U_{(n)}-U_{(n-1)},1-U_{(n)} ) <a\right)=1-(1-a)^{n+1}$ get $\mathbb P\left(\max(U_{(1)}, U_{(2)}-U_{(1)}, \cdots,U_{(n)}-U_{(n-1)} ) <a\right)$.

Comment: The Dirichlet $D_{n+1}(1,…,1)$ distribution is uniform over the $(n+1)$ dimension simplex.

Comment: @Xi'an Is something awry with that quote from Devroye's book? You have $n+1$ spacings which sum to $1$, so the max must be at least as big as $1/(n+1)$. But putting $a\geq 1/(n+1)$ in your expression does not give $0$ on the RHS. I looked up Lemma 2.1 on p.208 of Devroye, and it seems to give a result for min not for max: namely that $P(\min(...)<a)=1-(1-(n+1)a)^{n+1}$, for $a\leq 1/(n+1)$.

Comment: @JamesMartin: you are correct, my mistake!

Answer (score 3):

*Partial answer for small $a$*

For small $a$, specifically $a<\frac{1}{n}$, you can use the fact that the joint distribution of the order statistics is uniform with density $n!$ (see this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_the_uniform_distribution)). The probability can then be calculated by direct integration to obtain $n!\, a^n$.

In detail, $P\left(\max(U_{(1)}, U_{(2)}-U_{(1)}, \cdots,U_{(n)}-U_{(n-1)} ) <a\right)$ can be written as $P\left(U_{(1)}<a, U_{(2)}<U_{(1)}+a, \cdots,U_{(n)}<U_{(n-1)}+a \right)$, so can be evaluated as $$\int_{x_1=0}^a \int_{x_2=x_1}^{x_1+a}\cdots \int_{x_n=x_{n-1}}^{x_{n-1}+a} f(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n)\,dx_n\, dx_{n-1}\cdots dx_1$$ The density $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n)=n!$, as already referenced, so the integral evaluates to $n!\, a^n$.

If $a>\frac{1}{n}$ then the integral above, with $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n)=n!$, is an overestimate because $f$ is actually $n!\,I(x_n\leq 1)$ and will become zero at vectors $(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n)$ with $x_n>1$. If $a<\frac{1}{n}$ then $x_n$ is always $\leq 1$ in the above integration.

For general $a$, evaluating the above integral with $f=n!\,I(x_n\leq 1)$ is possible but looks messy. For example, for $n=2$, I obtained $2a^2$ for $a\leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $4a-2a^2-1$ for $a>\frac{1}{2}$.

You can easily check this by simulation in R...

```
   f<-function(x) # integral for n=2
{
  if(x<=0.5) return(2*x*x)
  if(x>0.5) return(4*x-2*x*x-1)
}

n=2
nsamples=100000
samples=array(0,dim=c(nsamples,n)) # sample[i,] is to be the i'th sample of n uniforms
samplemax=rep(0,nsamples) # samplemax[i] is the maximum of interest, computed for the i'th sample

for(i in 1:nsamples) samples[i,]<-sort(runif(n)) # samples[i,j] is now the j'th order statistic of sample i
for(i in 1:nsamples)
{
  shift=tail(samples[i,],-1)
  samplemax[i]=max(c(samples[i,1],shift-samples[i,1:(n-1)]))
}

a=(0:1000)/1000
cdf=rep(0,1001)
fa=rep(0,1001)
for(i in 1:1001) cdf[i]=length(samplemax[samplemax<=a[i]])/length(samplemax)
plot(a,cdf,type="l")

# Check for n=2
for(i in 1:1001) fa[i]=f(a[i])
points(a,fa,type="l",col="red")
```